# Checking for a null element with Java Vector class

Tags: java, vector, null

I am building a Heap data structure, but the part that is driving me nuts is checking for a null child value.

I am using a Vector, and I am comparing a parent against a child, but if there's only one child the program crashes since something like

```
vectorObject.get(i) //i'th element doesn't exist
```

will return an exception.

I can't check for the null element with something like

```
if (vectorObject.get(i) == null)
```

since running the get() method will automatically break the program, so how do you ACTUALLY check for a non-existing element without some unreadable weird hack-around??

Comment: A note from [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html): "Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to *use ArrayList in place of Vector.*"

Comment: thanks. but wouldn't I run into the same problem with an ArrayList as well?

Comment: That was more just general advice than a specific answer to your problem. I would actually recommend never using `Vector`, even in multithreaded programs. Instead, the [`ArrayList` doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) suggests using [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) in multithreaded environments.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that, this is for my own algorithm skills though, rather than production code. Also, I don't understand the downvote..I think that's a perfectly normal question. It's hard enough on SO to get any kind of points..sigh.

Comment: The down-vote wasn't from me—I don't understand it either. I would still recommend changing your `Vector` to an `ArrayList` just to get in the habit of using the correct data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem very confused. I think you need to re-read whatever reference you're using to design your heap data structure (or read [the relevant section of the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation)).

If your parent is at `0` then your children are at `2*(0)+1=1` and `2*(0)+2=2`. In this case, `1 < vectorObject.size()` will be true but `2 < vectorObject.size()` is false, meaning there is a left child but no right child.

Since the `Vector` (or `ArrayList` if you've switched as per my suggestion) is zero-based you need to check if `i < vectorObject.size()`, not `i <= vectorObject.size()`. If `i < vectorObject.size()` then `i` is a legal index.

***Update:***

There are two ways you can structure the logic here. If you have to handle the single-child case totally differently than the two-child case then this would probably work best:

```
int size = vectorObject.size();
if (2*i+2 < size) { /* Two-child case */ }
else if (2*i+1 < size) { /* One-child case */ }
else { /* No children case */ }
```

If you handle the two nodes separately, then nesting might be better:

```
int size = vectorObject.size();
if (2*i+1 < size) {
  // Handle left child
  if (2*i+2 < size) {
    // Handle right child
  }
  else {
    // No right child
  }
}
else { /* No children */ }
```

Comment: yeah I know this. And I can still implement it correctly. The problem is when a right child doesn't exist and a left child does. Using this method, that essentially means that just to check for a null value, I need to have two separate logic paths -- one for when left child exists without the right and one when both exist. As well as some more logic inside for the actual heap logic in each path. This would create some really unreadable code.

Comment: @volk - Refactoring some of the code out into new methods (e.g. `handleLeftChild` and `handleRightChild`) would probably help alleviate problems with less-readable code.

Comment: @volk - The reason I said "you seem very confused" in my answer is because you kept saying you need to "check for a null value." Hopefully you can now see that there's no need to check for `null` anywhere in this code—you just do bounds checking instead.

Answer (score 0):

do a try/catch:

```
try{

yourVector.get(int theElementYouWant);

}

catch(NullPointerException){

//well, I guess that element was null!

}
```